# How to parallel to serial in MATLAB/Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I want to design a simple communication channel in MATLAB/Simulink.

The quantizer block outputs the integer type, which I have converted int to binary by integer to binary block. 
my problem:
Say, input of int to binary block is N*1. Its output is N*M, where M is the number of bits used to represent every integer value. By which block can i convert the output of the size N*M to a NM*1 serial stream?

p.s: 
1-I haven't the Xilinx library installed. 
Cheeers

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395762/problem-with-parallel-to-serial-block-in-simulink) might help

Answer (score 0):

According to the ADC system below this system converts analog samples to 3 bits each and sends them in 1X3 matrix (parallal transmission) How to convert the transmission to serial transmission.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Reshape block present in Library Simulink->Math Operations.